# Cannot find the definition for sd_ble_enable() in nrf51822 source code

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

Could not browse some of the functions for pca10001->s110 softdevice. Is it something the firmware code this function sd_ble_enable() referring to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sd_ble_enable() is part of the softdevice code. A SoftDevice is a precompiled and linked binary software [1], therefore the definition for it and any softdevice function is not provided by nordic. Instead, many examples that use the function are included in the SDK and the function description can be found in ble.h header file.

[1] http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp